# Simplifying Squared Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have a question regarding pulling constants into a squared integral. I have the following integrals:

$$\left[\int_0^{\infty } x\, f(x) g (x)\, dx\right]^2+c^2\left[\int_0^{\infty } f(x) g (x)\, dx\right]^2= \,???$$

*where c here is a constant*

I'm curious if there's a way to pull c into the equation to make the inside of the integral have a form similar to $(x-c)$.

---

I know this is possible when the integrals are not squared like in the case of the following:

$$\left[\int_0^{\infty } x^2 f (x) g (x) \, dx\right]-\left[c^2 \int_0^{\infty } f (x) g (x) \, dx\right]=\int_0^{\infty } (x^2-c^2) f (x) g (x) \, dx$$

*(via the additive property of definite integrals)*

---

**Any tricks or walkthroughs to get 'c' into that top equation would be super helpful!!! Thank you!!!**

Comment: Note that in your second equation, you should have $(x^2 - c^2)$ instead of $(x - c)^2$

Comment: I don't see any nice way to condense this sum into a single integral. Maybe if you explained why you're trying to "pull the $c$ in", we could give you another way to approach the problem.

Comment: Great catch, @BenGrossmann! Going to edit that now!

Comment: It's easier to work with one function $h(x) = f(x)g(x)$ instead of two functions $f$ and $g$. Futher, $$c^2\left[\int_0^{\infty } f(x) g (x)\, dx\right]^2=\left[\int_0^{\infty } ch(x)\, dx\right]^2,$$ so you can pull $c$ into the second intergal. Now your question takes the next form: is it possible to make one intergral from a sum of squares of two intergals. The answer is negative.

Comment: Once you pulled the $c$ into the integral, remember that $a^2 + b^2 = (a-b)^2 + 2ab$ according to the binomial theorem. Choose $a$ and $b$ as your two integrals. So you will eventually have an error term $2ab$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, yeah that's a great question! So I'm trying to approach these integrals in a new direction. Historically, the original way it's represented is typically (x-c). But through a different approach we're getting an answer that takes on the form of the top equation. Having c inside the integral would make us feel a lot better about the approaches getting us to the same destination. I can get into the nitty-gritty of what the integrals actually are if you prefer! :)

Comment: @Caitlin It sounds like if there is a way of getting from one to the other, then it would be due to the nature of the specific functions $f$ and $g$. So yes, I think we need the "nitty gritty" to be able to say anything helpful

Comment: Why do the integrals converge?